# Lumen `php artisan migrate` not connecting to the database

Tags: php, laravel, lumen

I am new to Lumen micro framework of Laravel, and I didn't use Laravel before.

I want to make **Web Services** for mobile application. I am following this tutorial [tutorial](https://coderexample.com/restful-api-in-lumen-a-laravel-micro-framework/).

I have setup Lumen successfully on Linux base server

When I run command `php artisan migrate` I got this error

> [POD Exception]
>
> SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection Refused

I searched found this solutions on Stack Overflow but didn't worked for me, for example this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31917708/lumen-error-when-using-artisan-migrate/31920037#31920037).

I didn't get any other solutions. How can I proceed?

Comment: Do you have the .env file setup with your database info correctly?  It seems like it doesn't have the right credentials to the database or its not currently running.

Comment: Did you configure your database in your `.env` file?

Comment: My env file is correct and my db info also correct. i didn't do anything from yesturday, today i just try again php artisan migrate and it just worked :) i think i was cache issue may be i don't know.. -_-

Answer (score 2):

Your database credentials are not working, thus you can't connect to the database to run your migrations.

Try making a route with this code to see if your database is connected:

```
$app->get('/database', function () use ($app) {
    $db = app()->make('db');

    if ( $db->connection()->getDatabaseName() )
    {
        return 'Connected to the DB: ' . $db->connection()->getDatabaseName();
    }
    else
    {
        return 'Unable to establish database connection...';
    }
});
```

Then visit the `/database` route to see the results.

You need to set your database credentials in the `.env` file of Lumen, and make sure you reboot your local dev server for the .env files to take effect.

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=db_name
DB_USERNAME=forge
DB_PASSWORD=password
```

Also, if you are using MAMP for your local database, one thing you may need to do is specify your socket connection. You can do this by modifying the file `bootstrap/app.php` and adding this:

```
/**
 * Configuration
 */
$app['config']->set('database.connections.mysql.unix_socket', '/Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock');
```

It may not be a perfect copy paste solution, but something worth considering. It may at least point you in the right direction to look for database socket configuration in Lumen.

Comment: Thankyou so much for your valuable answer, i just try again today and migrate command has worked :) i think that was a cache issue... I will try your answer when i need to test my db connection :)